# dhtmlx gantt dynamicly load data using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, dhtmlx, gantt-chart

Trying to get the dhtmlx gantt to load json data on load of page.

## data_file.php (snip)

```
$colors = array(1=>"red", 2=>"green", 3=>"blue", 4=>"yellow", 5=>"orange", 6=>"grey");
$aryData = array();
if($project_tasks) {
    foreach($project_tasks as $aryTask) {
        $aryData[] =  array(
          "id" => $aryTask["pt_id"],
          "text" => $aryTask["pt_name"],
          "start_date" => date("d-m-Y", strtotime($aryTask["pt_start_date"])),
          "duration" => round((strtotime($aryTask["pt_end_date"]) - strtotime($aryTask["pt_start_date"]))/(60*60)),
          "open" => true,
          "color" => $colors[rand(1,6)]
        );
    }
}

$strData = json_encode($aryData, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
header("Content-type:application/json;");
echo "\"data\" : ".$strData;
```

delivers something like this (from chrome console):

```
"data" : [{"id":"152","text":"test3","start_date":"01-09-2015","duration":600,"open":true,"color":"yellow"},{"id":"153","text":"test1","start_date":"23-09-2015","duration":72,"open":true,"color":"grey"},{"id":"154","text":"test2","start_date":"15-09-2015","duration":264,"open":true,"color":"red"}]
```

## js-file.js (snip)

```
var data_url = basePath + "system/data_file.php?project_id=" + projectID;
$(".gantt").dhx_gantt({
scale_unit:"week",
step:1,
date_scale:"%W"
});
// var tasks = $(".gantt").dhx_gantt().load(data_url);
$(".gantt").dhx_gantt().load(data_url);
gantt.parse(tasks);
```

I try to "alert(tasks);" with a result of "undefined" or null.

I have tried syncronous ajax load of data:

```
var tasks = null;

$.ajax({
    url: data_url,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        tasks = data;
    }
});
```

and that gave same result -> null.

So I see why gantt will not load with data - there is no data in the tasks variable.

Does anyone have a running example ?

Kind regards

Lars

Answer (score 0):

Soo... I played around with the code..

And this is what I came up with so far. Seems it was the JSON that had to be in a specific way..

JS:

```
/* Gantt Start */

        var data_url = basePath + "system/print_gantt_project_data.php?project_id=" + projectID;

        gantt.config.readonly = true;
        gantt.config.scale_unit = "month"; 
        gantt.config.step = 1;
        gantt.config.date_scale = "%M";

        gantt.init("gantt_div");
        gantt.load(data_url, "json");
        gantt.render();
/* Gantt End */
```

Only problem with this approach - again so far - is that the dhtmlx_gantt does not render the tasks at first. Seems a kind of refresh is needed. (And I tried what is available in the API (http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_render.html)

Still trying to get that one fixed..

Oh, and the PHP file creating the json data:

/*Start*/

```
/* Create JSON array and print it for /js/system_project.js */
$colors = array(1=>"red", 2=>"green", 3=>"blue", 4=>"yellow", 5=>"orange", 6=>"grey");
$aryData = array();
if($project_tasks) {
    foreach($project_tasks as $aryTask) {
        $aryData[] =  array(
          "id" => $aryTask["pt_id"],
          "text" => $aryTask["pt_name"],
          "start_date" => date("d-m-Y", strtotime($aryTask["pt_start_date"])),
          "duration" => round((strtotime($aryTask["pt_end_date"]) - strtotime($aryTask["pt_start_date"]))/(60*60)),
          "open" => "true",
          "color" => $colors[rand(1,6)],
          "parent" => $aryTask["pt_parent"]
        );
    }
}

$strData = json_encode($aryData, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
header("Content-type:application/json;");
echo "{\"data\":".$strData."}";
```

Any knowledge on making stuff work correct, please do not hesitate to enter ;-)

/Lars